# Linq to SQL Dynamic Where Clause

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a simple query:

```
dim res = (From x In db.INVENTORies
         Where x.INVENTORY_ACTIVATION_DATE IsNot Nothing).count
```

I need to run this for 14 different date fields, so how do I run this where INVENTORY_ACTIVATION_DATE can be a variable/dynamic?

something like:

function GetCount(aField as string) as integer

```
return (From x In db.INVENTORies
        Where x.**<Use aField here>** IsNot Nothing).count
```

end function

Thanks in advance.
Steve

I've tried Dynamic Linq and PredicateBuilder, but there are no good examples for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### C# Eval Expression

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [C# Eval Expression](https://eval-expression.net/my-first-linq-dynamic)

The library is not free, but you can do pretty much any dynamic LINQ using the same syntax as C#.

*So it can be used in your VB.NET application, but you will need to use C# syntax for the dynamic part*

```vb
return context.Customers.WhereDynamic("x => x.AnyField != null && x.AnyField2 != null").count
```

As you can see, you simply need to create the string to execute dynamically.

#### LINQ Dynamic

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/

The same can be achieved with LINQ Dynamic. You can find some where example [here](https://dynamic-linq.net/basic-simple-query#more-where-examples)

You don't have to use the PredicateBuilder but simply create the string dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, but I have been unable to get any of that to work as I stated in my initial question.  Sorry but I'm not looking for a solution I have to pay for.  I'd rather just have 14 queries each with a different column name.  It's free.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Through much trail and error, I finally got this working.  I ended up using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).